# Javascript while loop freezing page

Tags: javascript

So the page keeps freezing when i run this function on firefox and google chrome i tried using a for loop didn't work as expected any ideas?

Thanks

```
   function grab_users() {

    var start_id = document.getElementById('start_range');
    start_id = start_id.value;

    var end_id = document.getElementById('end_range');
    end_id = end_id.value;

    var grabbed = document.getElementById('grabbed_users');
    while (start_id < end_id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/extract.php",
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'start_range': start_id},
            success: function(res) {
                var usernames = res;

                if (!usernames.valueOf() == "") {
                    usernames = usernames.replace('</br>', '');
                    grabbed.value += usernames + '\n';
                }
            }
        });
        start_id+=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The page should indeed 'freeze' until it completes. How many iterations are we talking about?

Comment: Looks like the usual AJAX problem, updating `grabbed` from inside the callback...

Comment: So how do i do it right the way?

Comment: @elclanrs: The OP's not using anything inside the success handler that varies for the loop, so that part's okay. (Doing a huge number of overlapping ajax calls, on the other hand...)

Comment: @RexJhonson: Why are you ignoring Luan's very useful question?

Comment: note that `start_id` is a string, and adding `1` doesn't do what the OP thinks

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, ah yes, it is an element. In general the code looks problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the values of inputs are always strings, you must convert them to Numbers before you use them, otherwise both, the comparision and the incrementation of `start_id` will not give the expected results(what ends in a infinite loop):

```
var start_id = parseInt(document.getElementById('start_range').value,10);
var end_id = parseInt(document.getElementById('end_range').value,10);
```

Suppose your `start_id` is `"20"` and your `end_id` is `"30"`. You'll start out with `"20" < "30"`, which is true; then on the next loop, you'll **append** `1` to the `start_id` string, giving us `"201" < "30"`. That's a *string* comparison, and so it's also true. Then `"2011" < "30"`, which is also true. And so on.

Using numbers corrects this.